# Spring MVC - "IllegalArgumentException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when get SOAP response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap

I'm beginner in Spring MVC. I want to get response from SOAP web service. But i get a error message.

[image: Error Message]

Here is my source code.

```
private static final String GET_DOCUMENT_SOAP_ACTION = "apvx:bus:ReportGenerator:{1D81BEDF-3894-45b2-99C9-95E50B1B9494}/Document_Get";

    @Autowired
    protected PathCentralWSTemplateFactory webServiceTemplateFactory;

    public DocumentGetResponse documentGet(DocumentGet request) {
        try {
            return (DocumentGetResponse) webServiceTemplateFactory.getClient().marshalSendAndReceive(request,
                    getCallback(GET_DOCUMENT_SOAP_ACTION));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
```

**PathCentralWSTemplateFactoryImpl**

```
public PathCentralWSTemplateFactoryImpl() throws SOAPException {
        marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
        MessageFactory obj =  MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
        if(obj != null){
            ((SaajSoapMessageFactory) messageFactory).setMessageFactory(obj);   
        }
        ((SaajSoapMessageFactory) messageFactory).setSoapVersion(org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11);
        url = "https://www.mypathcentral.net/...";

    }

@Override
    public WebServiceTemplate getClient() {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(messageFactory);
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller((Unmarshaller) marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(url);
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(getMessageSender());
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the framework you have going on here but I have an idea as to what's wrong with your code. You are getting a message that says no object reference. I believe this is because you are declaring GET_DOCUMENT_SOAP_ACTION as a static final. The static keyword causes the system to allocate static memory outside of the heap separate from any object. I think if you declare the string as a standard object this might clear up that issue but I'm not sure if that would cause problems with the rest of your code.